# What happens when we import same module from separate lazy loaded modules in angular 2?

Tags: angular

What happens when we import a `CertainModule` in two separate lazily loaded modules given the case the `CertainModule` is NOT imported in the `AppModule`(Root Module).

@Will it be downloaded twice as chunk when user navigate to both the modules one after another?

Thanks

Comment: It will be loaded once with the first module loaded that depends on it.

Comment: Read also https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-if-i-import-the-same-module-twice

Comment: Thank you for the response. So,Is it true that, all components from a module are loaded when we load a module (even if we just want to use only one component?).  Or this is also handled somehow ?

I know we can create a SharedModule and declare shareable component.

Comment: _Will it be downloaded twice as chunk when user navigate to both the modules one after another?_ - probably not if the `import` statement contains the same path, the module will be cached by the module loader the first time it loads it